# Decision curve analysis - importance of false negatives

Tags: model-evaluation, threshold

I'm implementing a decision curve analysis in my project and since the cost of screening is very low and has the added benefit of reassurance for the patients, false positives aren't of great concern- in contrast to false negatives. I think I don't fully understand the concept/how net benefit is actually calculated. How, if at all, are false negatives included in the calculation? is there a modification of "net benefit" that focuses on false negatives?